# videojs not working in angular 2 app

Tags: angular, video.js

I use a component with a function that executes the url of a video through a subscribe.

The tag is only displayed when the url exists.

The video tag is triggered normamenel, however the css is not executed.
I'm using video-js to video tag.

```
this.postServices.getPost(id).subscribe( (res) => {

this.video = 'http://127.0.0.1:9111/api/get/video.mp4';

})
```

Template

```
<video *ngIf="video"
                 class="video-js"
                 controls preload="metadata" autoplay="true" >
              <source [src]="video" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
```

Comment: If the video element is added, then it's not related to `*ngIf`

Comment: So, the element is displayed, but the css styling is not in place?

Comment: Exactly Armen. The CSS video-js does not show.

Comment: Gunter - It is not related to if, but must be related to loading, since the video-js css is not shown in the component.

Comment: The tag is executed, but the player style is not shown.

Comment: `*ngIf` is just adding a DOM element when `video` becomes truthy. I don't know video.js or what it is supposed to do.

Comment: The class video-js is what gives the player the style. This style does not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to add:

`<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">`

To your `<head></head>` section in your index.html

Also add the videojs script to your index.html:

`<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.8/video.js"></script>`

Then when you run the request for the url in your service you should init the player:

```
declare let videojs: any; // just to avoid TS stuffs for this demo
player: any;

this.postServices.getPost(id).subscribe( (res) => {
    this.video = 'http://127.0.0.1:9111/api/get/video.mp4';
    // Just to be sure that you have the video tag available
    setTimeout(() => player = videojs('player'), 100);
})
```

Template:

```
      <video *ngIf="video" id="player"
             class="video-js"
             controls preload="metadata" autoplay="true" >
          <source [src]="video" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
```

With that this should work, but this isn't an issue with `*ngIf`, it's related to the usage of the [videojs](http://videojs.com/getting-started/) lib.